# How to write hive regex to match condition 1 OR condition 2 and return whichever matches?

Tags: regex, hive

I need to have "or" logic in my regexp.

1. For example, from "foobar435" I would need the three numbers, so "435"
2. But from "barfoo543" I would need the three letters before the three numbers, so "foo"

Individually, the regexes would be "foobar([0-9]){3}" to get the first case, and "[a-zA-Z]{3}([0-9]{3})[a-zA-Z]{3}" to get the second case.  How do I get both cases at once with one regexp?  So, if the first regexp matches then return "435", but if not, return "foo"?

I am using hive so ideally I want to make one call only.  So far I have...

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT(myString, 'foobar([0-9]){3}', 1) AS columnName
```

Not sure how to add the second case into this.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use [lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) for this.

In your first case, you want to match three digits preceded by "foobar" (use lookbehind):

`(?<=foobar)[0-9]{3}`

In your second case, you want to match three letters preceded by three letters (use lookbehind) and followed by three digits (use lookahead):

`(?<=[a-zA-Z]{3})[a-zA-Z]{3}(?=\d{3})`

Note that, if I interpreted your requirements correctly, it looks like you flipped the numeric part with the second alpha part in your expression.

Now that you have your two expressions, you just need to combine them with an 'or':

`(?<=foobar)[0-9]{3}|(?<=[a-zA-Z]{3})[a-zA-Z]{3}(?=\d{3})`

One thing to be aware of is that this will also match words with additional word characters on either end, ie "xfoobar435x". If this is undesirable, add a word boundary `\b` to the beginnings of the lookbehinds and to the end of the lookahead.